# get attributes, even if they do not exist

Tags: groovy, sap-commerce-cloud

Please don't hate me, yes I want to do something really stupid.

I want to get `null` on every attribute if it does not exist. I found out that I can create the `propertyMissing` method:

```
class User {
    String name = "A"
}

Object.metaClass.propertyMissing() {
    null
}

u = new User();

println u?.name
println u?.namee
```

This prints:

```
A
null
```

Now I have the "great" Hybris system in my back :D

If I add the propertyMissing part on top of my script and run this in the Hybris groovy console, I still get the MissingPropertyException.

Is there another way to avoid the MissingPropertyException exception without having to work with hundreds of try catch? (*or hundreds of `println u?.namee ? u.namee : null`* isn't working)

/Edit: 1

I have the following use case (for the Hybris system):
I want to get all necessary information in a dynamic output from some pages. Why dynamic? Some page components have the attribute `headline` other `teaserHeadline` and some other `title`. To avoid to create each time an try catch or if else, I created a function which loops through possible attributes and if it's null it skips that one. For that I need to return null on attributes which doesn't exist.

Here is an example which should work, but it doesn't (don't run it on your live system):

```
import de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.search.FlexibleSearchQuery;
import de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.search.SearchResult;

flexibleSearch = spring.getBean("flexibleSearchService")

FlexibleSearchQuery query = new FlexibleSearchQuery("select {pk} from {ContentPage}");
SearchResult searchResult = flexibleSearch.search(query);

def i = 0;
def max = 1;
searchResult.result.each { page ->
    if (i < max) {
        gatherCMSPageInformation(page)
    }

    i++;
}

def gatherCMSPageInformation(page) {
    page.class.metaClass.propertyMissing() {
        null
    }

    println page.title2
}
```

Weird thing is, that if I run it a few times in a small interval, it starts to work. But I can't overwrite "null" to something else like "a". Also I noticed, to overwrite the Object class isn't working at all in Hybris.

/Edit 2:

I noticed, that I'm fighting against the groovy cache. Just try the first example, change `null` with `a` and then try to change it again to `b` in the same context, without restarting the system.

Is there a way to clear the cache?

Comment: Maybe you could explain your actual use-case, there might be a better solution to your real problem.

Comment: I don't know the Hybris system, but if you run as a script, you would probably need to use this instead of Object, to set it on the script generated class: 
 this.metaClass.propertyMissing()

Comment: I've copy paste your code in hybris groovy console (6.7) and I get the expected result. I don't get your point. Above code don't work in your groovy console?

Comment: I added my use case and an example to my post.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use the groovy elvis operator?

```
println u?.namee ?: null
```

Comment: I noticed that I still get exception